# How to point to a external main html file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I have a Electron project but I need to point to a localhost file (A ZeroNet site) to be the main html file. Can it work like a normal main html file, with all the APIs/scripts?

Comment: What to you mean "main html file"?

Comment: If you understand about Electron (its tagged here), this question cannot be a need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Electron</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

### JavaScript

```
var electron = require('electron'),
    app = electron.app,
    BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

var path = require('path');

app.on('ready', function () {
  // Window
  var win = new BrowserWindow({
    darkTheme: true
  });

  // Load HTML file
  win.loadURL('file://' + path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

Moreover, you can load external URLs. Example:

```
win.loadURL('https://stackoverflow.com/');
```

So localhost should work like a charm...

Comment: Thanks anyways. But I'm talking about a file located in localhost (ZeroNet). Precisely, http://127.0.0.1:43110/1DCRSfb95muP5N78v1fQ8DN8CxbjEfXewT